# Toggle Show/Hidden Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to hide a sheet and only show it when i double click on a specific sheet.
let's say i have sheet1 and sheet2. I want sheet2 to be always hidden until i double click on a cell (anywhere on the sheet1 not a specific cell) in sheet1 and hide it again when i leave it.Is it possible?
I've read something about

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object,ByVal Target As Range, ByVal Cancel As Boolean)
```

but i haven't be able to use it.
Thank You for Time and Help

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this, both in the sheet1 module (right-click sheet tab, view code and paste code)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Cancel = True

Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetVisible

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()

Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetHidden

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, What's this expression for? `Cancel = True`

Answer (score 1):

place this in Sheet1 code pane:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

and place this in sheet2 code pane:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: sheet2 is hidden but when i double click on sheet1 sheet2 is still hidden. Do i have to click on a specific area?

Comment: no. I tested my code and it works as intended. Double check you placed the event handler where I told you to. Do you have any other events handler in sheet2 code pane? You may also follow what's happening by placing breakpoints in your code and go on step by step with F8

Comment: I can't launch the macro in sheet1 (`Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick`), no i don't have anything in sheet2 and 1 beside your code

Comment: you may have events disabled. run `Application.EnableEvents = True` from Immediate Window before starting debugging

Comment: You could remove `.Activate` line and change other line to `.Visible = Not .Visible`

Comment: @Ibrahimatto, did you get through it?

Comment: @DisplayName I change `.activate = True` with `.activate = xlSheetVisible`and it seems to be working

Comment: @DisplayName But when i launch the excel file again it doesn't seem to work automatically. I always have to go on the vba editor

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following using Excel 2010 under Windows 7, ...paste the following into the "ThisWorkbook" code pane...hope this helps...

```
Dim strLastActive As String
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    strLastActive = ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If ActiveSheet Is ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") Then
        If Not ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    If strLastActive = "Sheet2" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```